# Linux Shell script (bash) to change IP address of remote machine using SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ip

I'd like to have a shell script to change the IP address of a remote machine using SSH.

The problem I am having is that both SSH and remote commands require passwords. I am using 'expect' to handle the password input and this works works well in isolation for each step, but not combined.

i.e. I have a separate script on the remote machine to change the IP address. This works when running manually on the remote machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set ipaddr [lindex $argv 0]
set password "mypassword"
set timeout 2

if {[llength $argv] == 0} {
  send_user "Usage: ./set_ip.sh ipaddress/24\n"
  exit 1
}

spawn sudo nmcli dev modify eth0 ipv4.addresses $ipaddr

expect {
    password { send "$password\r" ; exp_continue }
    timeout { send_user "\nFailed to get password prompt\n"; exit 1 }
    eof exit
}
close
```

And I have a script to perform the SSH, then call the above remote script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set target [lindex $argv 0]
set newipaddr [lindex $argv 1]
set password "mysshpassword"
set timeout 2

spawn ssh $target

expect {
    password: {send "$password\r"}
    timeout { send_user "\nFailed to get password prompt\n"; exit 1 }
    eof exit
}

send "~/set_ip.sh $newipaddr/r"

send "exit\r"
close
```

When the remote script gets called, it seems to run okay but the password prompt following the nmcli command is never received.

If someone could advise where I am going wrong I'd be grateful.

Also, this is the first time I've used bash, so feel free to express critique.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use sshpass?

Comment: have you tried using this approach to run a remote command? e.g. ssh username@server 'ls /' ? Also you should be able to bypass password using public key of a server - sth. like https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

Comment: Thanks. This approach worked i.e. spawn ssh $user@$current_ip "./set_ip.sh $new_ip $password"